# JQuery Validate Custom Error messages in multiple places (top of form and at form level)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the JQuery Validate plugin to handle validation for my forms. I have a requirement to have the error at 2 places:

1. Top of the form
2. At the field level

I have it working at the field level, but how do I get it to work for both the top and at the field level.

At the top of the form, I want to have something like this:

```
<p>You have the following error messages:</p>

     <li>First Name - This is a required field</li>
     <li>Last Name - This a required field</li>
     <li>Email Address - This is a required field</li>
```

At the form level, i have error messages showing up such as this which is working:

```
 First Name
 This is a required field
 [                        ]

 Last Name
 This is a required field
 [                        ]

 Email
 This is a required field
 [                        ]
```

Here is the HTML Code

```
 <html>
 <body>
   <div id="errormessages"></div>
   <form id="myform">
      <label for="firstname" class="required">First name</label> <input type="text" required="required" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="textInput" /></div>
      <label for="lastname" class="required">Last name</label> <input type="text" required="required" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="textInput" /></div>
      <label for="email" class="required">Email</label> <input type="text" required="required" name="email" id="email" class="textInput" /></div>
   </form>
 </body>
 <html>
```

Jquery code for error messages placed at the form level:

```
   $("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true
        }

    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

          error.insertBefore(element);
    }

   });
```

so how would i build the code to have it at both locations?

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the **relevant** HTML markup.  The `name` attributes in your HTML do not match your jQuery and the `<form>` is missing an `id`.  It's also invalid; a bunch of stray `</div>` tags.

Comment: @Sparky thanks for spotting this. I have corrected the attributes to match the HTML and the Jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"so how would i build the code to have it at both locations?"*

See the `showErrors` option as contained [in the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

This will give you a good start (needs some tweaking)...

```
$("#myform").validate({
    // your rules here,

    // call back for placement of messages within form
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    },

    // callback for custom error display
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

        // summary of number of errors on form
        var msg = "Your form contains " + this.numberOfInvalids() + " errors, see details below.<br/>"

        // loop through the errorMap to display the name of the field and the error
        $.each(errorMap, function(key, value) {
            msg += key + ": " + value + "<br/>";
        });

        // place error text inside box
        $("#errormessages").html(msg);

        // also show default labels from errorPlacement callback
        this.defaultShowErrors(); 

        // toggle the error summary box
        if (this.numberOfInvalids() > 0) {
            $("#errormessages").show();
        } else {
            $("#errormessages").hide();
        }

    } // end showErrors callback
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/M5pzA/**

Comment: This works great. I went to the JSFiddle as you suggested and was playing around with it. I hit the submit button leaving the 3 fields blank. Then i clicked on the error message section where is says Your form contains 3 errors. I see the 3 errors for first name, last nand email. However, by accident, i clicked on the text Your form contains 3 errors and the 3 error messages below disappear. Do you know why?

Comment: @MoxieC, it's not the click but rather the blur event of leaving a field that triggers it all to update. Like I said, it's just a start... you'll need to make some adjustments.

Comment: is there a way for disabling the blur event as I dont want my summary error messages to disappear until the person hits the submit button.

Comment: @MoxieC, if you don't want validation until the submit button is clicked set `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` options to `false`.  See http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate for all options.

Comment: @SuccessMan, maybe you should accept one or two of my previous answers before asking me specifically for even more help.

Comment: Somehow I had to add `if (this.numberOfInvalids() != errorList.length) return;` at the beginning of the `showErrors` function. The code was entering it multiple times and only in the first entry the elements in `errorMap` were actually correct.