# jQuery Validation Plugin - show error messages and error summary

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need your help to solve a problem. I am using jQuery Validation plugin to validate the forms and I want to display validation summary as well as validation messages with each invalid field.
I tried the following code but i ran into 2 problems;

**PROBLEM 1:**
Error messages from invalid fields are not showing.

**PROBLEM 2:**
The error summary is displaying the list of all errors but without the name of the fields. I think the plugin uses the 'errorList' array which holds both the name of the element as well as its error message, but i have no idea how to use this. Ref: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

HTML

```
<form id="theForm" class="formContainer">
   <div id="errorSummary">
      <div class="summaryTitle">
         <!-- FOR ERROR TITLE -->
      </div>
      <ul>
         <!-- FOR ERROR LIST -->
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="formbox">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="required">       
   </div>
   <div class="formbox">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Last Name" class="required">       
   </div>
   <button type="Submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#theForm").validate({
     debug:true,
        errorLabelContainer: "#errorSummary ul",
        wrapper: "li",
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                if (errors) {                       
                  var message = errors == 1
                    ? '<h4>Submission Failed</h4>You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
                    : '<h4>Submission Failed</h4>You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
                  $("#errorSummary div.summaryTitle").html(message);
                  $("#errorSummary").show();
                } else {
                  $("#errorSummary").hide();
                }
        },
   });
});
</script>
```

***PLEASE NOTE:*** I am already using `errorPlacement` property of the plugin for other use

Comment: *"PLEASE NOTE: I am already using `errorPlacement` property of the plugin for other use"* ~ since that particular function is solely responsible for placing the error messages next to each field, don't you think that may be the root cause of your missing messages, and something you should be showing us here?

Comment: I also think you should be using `showErrors` instead of `invalidHandler`.   Notice that `this.defaultShowErrors()` will cause the default messages to appear next to each field; unless you've broken that by improperly over-riding the `errorPlacement` callback.  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors

Comment: @Sparky thanks friend... i will sure look into 'errorplacment'. i tried 'showerror' but due to my low skills in scripting.. i failed to use it to show both the element name and error msg

Comment: See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19729959/594235

Comment: i will look into your reference link. can u place your message in form of answer so that i can mark if it solves my problem.

Comment: Your question was closed as a "duplicate"... therefore no further answers are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it in angular.js. include angular-validator.js and just use the input field like this

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" validate-on="blur" required required-message="'required'" readonly>
```

where required-message is the message you want to display

Hope it works for you

Comment: thanks friend, i will sure look into this... seeing your simple code it seems far better option than that plugin

Comment: you can read on it here https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator

Comment: @user1231648, first off, that's just a different plugin.  Secondly, the jQuery Validate plugin works practically the same, and this answer does not even come close to solving your question.

Comment: @Sparky it suppose to be an alternative to achieving the same result. i stated it categorically in the answer. i don't get why you should vote it down

Comment: Suggesting an alternative plugin is not a good answer, but it does not solve the original problem in either case.  The OP wants his error messages in a detailed summary as well as next to each field.  Your answer only provides for the latter.